# Как сдвинуть весь блок текс в теге nav

Tags: html, css, css3

Можно ли сдвинуть содержимое тега nav автоматически направо без приписывание каждому тексту элемента команду padding-right как изначально указано ниже? Спасибо!

```css
body {
  width: 1440px;
}

nav {
  background: #51a8c7;
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  color: #111;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  line-height: 1;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
}

nav ul {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.search {
  margin-left: 700px;
}

.about {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.contact {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="search">Search</li>
      </a>
      <li class="about">About Us</li>
      <li class="contact">Contact</li>
      <li class="main">Main</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nav {display: flex; justify-content: space-around;}

Comment: Выложите HTML, чтобы можно было на Вашем примере найти решение и продемонстрировать Вам

Comment: @hisbvdis <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
           <li class="search">Search</li></a>
           <li class="about">About Us</li>         
           <li class="contact">Contact</li>
           <li class="main">Main</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для списка `<ul>` задайте свойство `display: flex;` и `justify-content: flex-end;`.

Для самих элементов `li` следует добавить какие-то внешние отступы боковые, чтобы промежутки были `margin: 0 15px;`

Также, я удалил все лишние свойства

[Результат на CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/ZEzWXbx)

Результат на StackOverflow

```css
body {
    width: 1440px;
}

nav {
    background: #51a8c7;
    width: 80%;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    color: #111;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    line-height: 1;
}

nav li {
    margin: 0 15px;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    
    padding-top: 6px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="search">Search</li></a>
        <li class="about">About Us</li>
        <li class="contact">Contact</li>
        <li class="main">Main</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо!

Comment: @Daniyar, если ответ помог, можете отметить его решением.

Comment: я бы с удовольствием отметил, но не знаю как. Я новичок тут. Не подскажете как это сделать? Спасибо!

Comment: @Daniyar, нажмите на галочку возле вопроса: https://take.ms/sZBY0